# align divs with the top inline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i've got a div containing two other divs that should be displayed with the tops inline. I've got the problem that they are intended to be on one level at the top, but when i fill them with a different number of lines of text one is getting pushed upwards. It would be awesome if both divs would have the same size and would be aligned exactly inline.

**The CSS of the parent div:**

```
#parent{
position:relative;
border:1px solid black;
width:303px;
}
```

**The CSS of the first div:**

```
#firstdiv{  
position:absolute; 
bottom:0; 
left:0; width:150px; 
border:1px solid black;
}
```

**The CSS of the second div:**

```
#seconddiv{  
position:absolute; 
bottom:0; 
right:0;
width:150px; 
border:1px solid black;
}
```

**The result:**

[image]

**[JSfiddle!](https://jsfiddle.net/rc0nqcd7/)**

Comment: Your total width is `304px` => `150px` of each element + `2px` of each border(left+right [each 1px] in both element) = `304px`

Comment: change #parent `width` to `304px`

Comment: Thanks, but it didnt solve my problem

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle and include your html too, that could help to find your problem better

Comment: Post your html code as well

Comment: ...and the rest of relevant CSS..because you can't get result shown on image with CSS you have posted...

Comment: @Sarius Are you expecting to get a result like the one you have posted?

Comment: exactly, also please be clearer about your main goal. do you want the test to show and the other div to match the height?

Comment: Also explain the context around this a little bit more. From the image you have shown, I would say you should not go with absolute positioning here to begin with.

Comment: I edited it, you can take a look again.

Comment: To be honest none of the below answers are real answer. You have to modify your `html` structure based on your needs and use `top:0;` instead of `bottom:0;`, ofc after you modified your `html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all position attributes and use `display: table-cell` in both first and second divs

see below snippet :

```css
#parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;  
}

#firstdiv {
  display: table-cell;
  
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#seconddiv {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent"> <span>Hello text<span>
  <div id="firstdiv">Stack </div>
  <div id="seconddiv">Overflow ing text and text adn text and other text </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try flex like this :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

#parent span {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <span>some content</span>
  <div class="item">
    some content
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    more more content and even more
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using Flex is both heavier than plain CSS and not supported by all browsers and platforms

Comment: @Itamar but i think it doesn't deserve a downvote ... and flex is supported by more than 80% of browser https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 2):

If this is how you want it to look according to your screenshot.  Using position:absolute will be a disaster as you add more elements to it. Use flex instead.

> You can see that the child containers maintain there original height. That is because of the class flex-item using flex-start to align them at top. but if you want them to occupy full height. Just remove flex-start;

```css
#parent {
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 303px;
  text-align: center;
}

.sub-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
  align-self: flex-start; //Use this only if you want uneven heights and want to align them from top
}

#firstdiv {
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#seconddiv {
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  Hello Stack overflow!
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div id="firstdiv" class="flex-item">
      First div with more content
    </div>
    <div id="seconddiv" class="flex-item">
      second div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using Flex is both heavier than plain CSS and not supported by all browsers and platforms

Comment: @Itamar Flex browser support: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp In before you downvote other's answers. They did provide a working and a clean solution just because you can achieve them with table doesn't mean it is wrong. And talking about table, it doesn't provide as much customization or alignment of data in a clean manner than flex, so food for thought.

Comment: @Itamar and why you think table is better ? we don't downvote answer because there is 5% of browser that doesn't support flex

Comment: I use flex a lot, but it not the immediate fix for a problem that can be solved without it

Comment: @Itamar Do you see the OP asking for a fix using a certain CSS attribute? And flex is no rough alternative but is designed for this purpose.

Comment: @Itamar `but it not the immediate fix for a problem that can be solved without it` : it's only your opinion and am sure a lot of people don't agree with it

Comment: I am not intending to open a debate here, but there is an old debate on the web when and where to use Flex. you can search. I am a flex user and fan, but i know i should not use it everywhere. debate example  http://brolik.com/blog/when-to-use-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Set the top of both absolute positioned children to the same value.

e.g. 20px or desired value

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp

i.e.

```css
#firstdiv {  
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 150px; 
  border: 1px solid black;
  top: 20px
}

#seconddiv {  
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0; 
  right: 0;
  width: 150px; 
  border: 1px solid black;
  top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `table` display attributes
This will make sure all the cells are same size and will let you remove the positioning.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/itamarsh/2go7m2jq/2/)

```css
#parent {
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 303px;
}

#content {
    display: table-row;
}

#firstdiv {  
    width: 50%; 
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid black;
} 

#seconddiv {  
    display: table-cell ;
    width: 50%; 
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="content">
    Hello Stackoverflow!
  </div>
  
  <div id="firstdiv">
    first div with more content
  </div>
  <div id="seconddiv">
    second div
  </div>
</div>
```